# Raspbian openVINO - no module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, raspbian, opencv

I have been configuring openVINO on my Raspberry pi 2 B, and [followed these instructions.](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html)

I was successfully able to run the "object_detection_sample_ssd" demonstration, but that is where my luck ended with the tutorial. I tried to run the openCV test, and it didn't work. Here's what I have gathered so far.

```
01
    pi@raspberrypi:~/build $ python3
02
    Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
03
    [GCC 8.2.0] on linux
04
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
05
    >>> import cv2
06
    Traceback (most recent call last):
07
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
08
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
09
    >>>
10
    [1]+  Stopped                 python3
```

Here's my PYTHONPATH

```
 1
    pi@raspberrypi:~/build $ echo $PYTHONPATH
2
    /opt/intel/openvino//python/python3.7:/opt/intel/openvino//deployment_tools/model_optimizer:
```

let me know what other information I can provide.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: What is the result of just `python` then `import cv2`?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Same output. I solved the problem by downgrading to an earlier version of raspbian.